# Ubuntu 18.02 LTS detects monitor but remains black

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, gpu-driver, ubuntu-drivers

On Dell G3 15 with GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 I am connecting to an external (acer) monitor via HDMI. I do not have any image (the screen is black) sometimes is coverd in blue dots or blue lines.

I ensured that:

- The HDMI cable is not damage
- The monitor is working
- I tried on several new monitors
- I tried different refresh rates
- I tried on xorg driver and several NVIDIA drivers
- Switching to Wayland; Ubuntu 16.04 and 19.04
- `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Xrandr outputs:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
   624x464       59.95  
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.02  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1680x1050 (0x4c) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1280x1024 (0x54) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x55) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x800 (0x61) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
  1024x768 (0x69) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x78) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x79) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  640x480 (0x87) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```

All logs when connecting the monitor.

```
==> /var/log/syslog <==
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):

==> /var/log/Xorg.0.log <==
[  2386.226] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
[  2386.226] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[  2386.226] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2386.226] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  2386.256] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
[  2386.256] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[  2386.256] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2386.256] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  2386.286] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
[  2386.286] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[  2386.286] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2386.286] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  2386.337] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[  2386.420] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
[  2386.420] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[  2386.420] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2386.420] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  2386.450] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
[  2386.450] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[  2386.450] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2386.450] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 

==> /var/log/syslog <==
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jul  5 12:19:23 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1539]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jul  5 12:19:24 m gsd-color[1330]: no xrandr-Acer Technologies-R231-T6GEE0012411 device found: Failed to find output xrandr-Acer Technologies-R231-T6GEE0012411

==> /var/log/Xorg.0.log <==
[  2386.617] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
[  2386.617] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[  2386.617] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2386.617] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  2386.647] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): connected
[  2386.647] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[  2386.647] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer R231 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2386.647] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

Xrandr on xorg:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.02  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Update 1:

journalctl | grep -i nvidia

```
iul 05 13:56:25 m kernel: nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
iul 05 13:56:25 m kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
iul 05 13:56:25 m kernel: nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
iul 05 13:56:25 m kernel: nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 236
iul 05 13:56:25 m kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
iul 05 13:56:25 m kernel: NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  430.26  Tue Jun  4 17:40:52 CDT 2019
iul 05 13:56:25 m kernel: nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  430.26  Tue Jun  4 17:45:09 CDT 2019
iul 05 13:56:25 m kernel: [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
iul 05 13:56:26 m systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[982]: Verbose syslog connection opened
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[982]: Now running with user ID 122 and group ID 127
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[982]: Started (982)
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[982]: Failed to query NVIDIA devices. Please ensure that the NVIDIA device files (/dev/nvidia*) exist, and that user 122 has read and write permissions for those files.
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[982]: PID file unlocked.
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[978]: nvidia-persistenced failed to initialize. Check syslog for more details.
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[982]: PID file closed.
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[982]: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[982]: Shutdown (982)
iul 05 13:56:26 m systemd[1]: nvidia-persistenced.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
iul 05 13:56:26 m systemd[1]: nvidia-persistenced.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
iul 05 13:56:26 m systemd[1]: Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
iul 05 13:56:26 m kernel: [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
iul 05 13:56:26 m kernel: nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in 8 mode, major device number 234
iul 05 13:56:26 m systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[1139]: Verbose syslog connection opened
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[1139]: Now running with user ID 122 and group ID 127
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[1139]: Started (1139)
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[1139]: device 0000:01:00.0 - registered
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[1139]: Local RPC services initialized
iul 05 13:56:26 m systemd[1]: Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[1139]: Received signal 15
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[1139]: Socket closed.
iul 05 13:56:26 m systemd[1]: Stopping NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[1139]: PID file unlocked.
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[1139]: PID file closed.
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[1139]: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
iul 05 13:56:26 m nvidia-persistenced[1139]: Shutdown (1139)
iul 05 13:56:26 m systemd[1]: Stopped NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
iul 05 13:56:26 m kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input26
iul 05 13:56:27 m systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
iul 05 13:56:27 m nvidia-persistenced[1217]: Verbose syslog connection opened
iul 05 13:56:27 m nvidia-persistenced[1217]: Now running with user ID 122 and group ID 127
iul 05 13:56:27 m nvidia-persistenced[1217]: Started (1217)
iul 05 13:56:27 m nvidia-persistenced[1217]: device 0000:01:00.0 - registered
iul 05 13:56:27 m nvidia-persistenced[1217]: Local RPC services initialized
iul 05 13:56:27 m systemd[1]: Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
```

Comment: `journalctl` cat give more details over `/var/log/syslog`. Try using `journalctl | grep -i nvidia` Also with my new 4K monitor I couldn't get 60Hz to work and had to use `cvt` to generate frequency of 54Hz.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix i just edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Problem appears to lie within nvidia persistence daemon. Here's what my working system looks like from last boot (I suspend and resume many times a day instead of rebooting):

```bash
Jun 21 17:24:31 alien systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
Jun 21 17:24:31 alien nvidia-persistenced[1102]: Verbose syslog connection opened
Jun 21 17:24:31 alien nvidia-persistenced[1102]: Now running with user ID 122 and group ID 131
Jun 21 17:24:31 alien nvidia-persistenced[1102]: Started (1102)
Jun 21 17:24:31 alien nvidia-persistenced[1102]: device 0000:01:00.0 - registered
Jun 21 17:24:31 alien nvidia-persistenced[1102]: Local RPC service initialized
Jun 21 17:24:31 alien systemd[1]: Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
Jun 21 17:24:32 alien kernel: nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-30fab9bc-fe6f-ec05-e8e6-c151a1a96121) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
```

I also had problems with `nvidia-persistenced` when I first setup my laptop and it took some googling to fix.

**Note:** If you prefer your question to have color syntax highlighting use this in your question:

```bash
<!-- Language-all: lang-bash -->
```

---

As per comment request:

```bash
$ cat /etc/default/grub | grep ^GRUB_CMD

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth fastboot acpiphp.disable=1 pcie_aspm=force vt.handoff=7 i915.fastboot=1 nopti nospectre_v2 nospec"
```

Comment: should it be in persistence-mode or not? coud you send me your grup config?

Comment: @NitescuLucian my grub file? ie `/etc/default/grub` you mean?

Comment: yes, i think my issues is somehow related to: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ao4kyp/new_dell_g3_3579_freeze_on_various_ubuntu_versions/

Comment: @NitescuLucian Done. Note `acpiphp` is needed for NVMe M.2 Gen 3.0 x 4 SSD.